# Remove white space in table view

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a view controller, part of which contains a table view. I am encountering white space before my cells begin which is throwing off the position of my search bar:

[image: When searching]

But this doesn't occur when not searching. I've found out that it is due to the property `hidesNavigationBarWhenPresenting` and when true it solves my problem:

[image: Working properly]

However this gets rid of my navigation bar, which I'd like to keep.

Unlike others with a similar problem, adjusts scroll view insets ticked off and changing section header height does not help.

Comment: What object is the `addToDictionary` property a member of?
Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Stephen I apologise for the confusion - autocorrect changed the name of the property. It is actually hidesNavigationBarWhenPresenting

Comment: Looks like search bar is pushed down by navigation header height. How did you set the search bar's constraint?

Comment: HMHero The search bar was created programmatically, and is placed in the table header view of my table view, so it has no constraints.